# TeX Live cant find packages that were installed via tlmgr

Tags: pdftex, texlive, linux, kpathsea

Sorry if this has already been answered but I couldn't find a solution that works. I'm on arch Linux and after a long and painful install of texlive, I managed to download packages with tlmgr. To give as much info as I can, I installed it with `sudo pacman -S texlive-most`. This is the same for all packages but for this example I'll use `amsmath`.  I ran `tlmgr install amsmath`, which now returns

```
 tlmgr.pl: package repository https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/systems/texlive/tlnet (verified)
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: amsmath
```

I wrote a simple main.tex file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\includepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
        Hello World!
\end{document}
```

and ran it, getting this (changed username btw):

```
$ pdflatex  ./main.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18>
(/home/username/texmf/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/home/username/texmf/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \includepackage
                   {amsmath}
```

Here's a couple things I thought would be useful:

```
$ locate amsmath.sty
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lwarp/lwarp-amsmath.sty
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/onlyamsmath/onlyamsmath.sty
/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex-dev/amsmath/amsmath.sty

$ which latex
/usr/bin/latex

$ which pdflatex 
/usr/bin/pdflatex

$ locate tlmgr
/usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgr.pl
/usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl
/usr/share/tlpkg/tltcl/tlmgr.gif
```

I would really appreciate any help I could get with getting LaTeX to find my packages and am happy to provide anything else. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: `\includepackage` is not a command you meant `\usepackage` but note you have conflicting tex trees in /usr/share and `/home/username/texmf` you are using the linux system tex so you should update with your linux package manager not tlmgr.

Comment: Packages are usually loaded with `\usepackage`, not with `\includepackage` (in fact `\includepackage` is not defined in the LaTeX kernel). Do things work with `\usepackage{amsmath}` instead of `\includepackage{amsmath}`?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I cant believe I missed that, I guess my LaTeX is rustier than I thought haha. I was using overleaf for years and am completely new to running LaTeX locally. How do I update my package manager? Thanks so much!

Comment: @JoshuaA  I don't know pacman but I guess given you started `sudo pacman -S texlive-most` something like `sudo pacman -S texlive-full` but it's inconceivable that you have not installed amsmath already if you have latex. (it is actually one of the required packages) you probably want to lose everything under `/home/username/texmf/tex/latex/base` as it will be masking the system tex tree

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks so much for your help, can't tell you how much I appreciate your time! Ill definitely look into it once I get the rest of my setup complete.